# Why am I getting a 'Failed to find a valid digest ' error?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

In my reactapp created by create-react-app I suddenly have an error in chrome when I try to run my app:

```
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js' with computed
SHA-256 integrity 'hW0einVybma+FCDLYbayWASTmGI9JBE1dkrmPvDzJXQ='. The
resource has been blocked.
```

However in IE it works fine. All I did was changing a label on a Button component. How can I avoid this error on chrome?

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like the feature is simply doing what it's intended to do.

Do you have compression enabled in your Chrome for Android browser?
Google may be minifiying your CSS before sending it to your phone causing the signature to be invalid.

SSL prevents this from happening. Maybe we should look for https in PUBLIC_URL and toggle this feature based on that.

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/data-compression

Comment: You literally copied the whole text from a Facebook link I was just looking at.